# Setting format of date time picker dynamically in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I want to set format of date to dd-mm-yyyy for control date time picker,i m able to create date time picker dynamically but can not set its format to dd-mm-yyyy 
plz do needful....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried just setting the [`DateTimePicker.CustomFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) property?

```
picker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
picker.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

(Note the MM for months; mm is for minutes.)

Answer (score 2):

Set format type to custom first:

```
DateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Comment: thank u its working with change as                          dtp.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtp.CustomFormat ="dd-MM-yyyy";